# Resource not found when asp.net mvc application deployed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I deployed my ASP.NET MVC app to the server. My Site name is: `http://server_name/Company_Reports`.

Everything works fine except when I redirect to some views.
For example when in `.aspx` web form I redirect:

```
 Response.Redirect("/FCDReports/DailyReports/");
```

In my website the site name `Company_Reports` disappears and the Url becomes:

`http://server_name/FCDReports/DailyReports/` and is not found because it should be:

`http://server_name/Company_Reports/FCDReports/DailyReports/`

How can I keep the site name `Company_Reports` in the url?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Response.Redirect

```
Response.Redirect("~/FCDReports/DailyReports/");
```

Or

```
 Response.Redirect("FCDReports/DailyReports/");
```